# Getting VSCODE like font usage in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I want to recreate VScode like visual/text in Indesign.

I can't get the apostrophe to be vertical and the overall feeling is not the same as I would like somebody got tips for me how to make this better??

Kindest regards,
The data is false so no worries there ;)
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960057/which-font-is-used-in-visual-studio-code-editor-and-how-to-change-fonts

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The font is Consolas.  I'm not really sure what the question is here. Also, not sure what you mean by "apostrophe", since there are no apostrophe's in the example you posted, and what do you mean by "it's not the same"?  Not the same as what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe you don't want full on syntax highlighting but I'll outline all of the steps anyway. It should cover all you need to know.

1. Copy code from VSCode
2. Paste into Microsoft Word

   - Other text editors could/should work too, but I do happen to know that while LibreOffice does take it in with full color and everything, it loses indentation for some reason. Never had the need to look into it further than that.
   - You may want to remove the background here. If you don't, you can still do it later in Indesign in the `paragraph` options by unchecking `Shading`.
3. Save it as `.doc`, `.docx`, or even `.rtf`
4. In Indesign use the command `File > Place (Cmd+D)` and in the `open files` dialog make sure to check `Show import options`
5. Then to make sure the double quotes remain the same as in VSCode uncheck `Use typographer's quotes` in the import options

**Other things...**

6. I'd recommend putting the code inside a single cell table, so it's easy to give it a new background color and inset if necessary. It just generally makes it easier to handle. You should 100% create `table style(s)` and `cell style(s)` so it's easy to apply to any new additions.
7. If you need to move the text around in the document after importing
   it (copy&paste), you may have to go to `Preferences > Type > Use typographer's quotes` and uncheck it before pasting the code back
   in. If you move the whole table, you shouldn't have to worry about them
   changing.
8. You might want to turn off: `ligatures`, `hyphenation` and also `shading`, if you didn't remove the background color in Word.
9. After you've imported it once and disabled typographers quotes, you should be able to then drag in text without them changing the quotes.

[image]

---

Some code editors might have extension(s) for exporting straight to [`.rtf`](https://github.com/lucasmazza/copy-as-rtf) or `.pdf`.